# Divide div to left, right , bottom in html

Tags: html, css

This is the layout i want,

[image]

I made some with code, but i'm not sure how to do after this.

[html]

```
  <div id="content">
        <div id="left">left</div>
        <div id="right">right</div>
        <div id="bottom">bottom</div>    
    </div>
```

[css]

```
  #content{
        /* the width in here will be changed 
        width: this requirment will be changed
        i dont' want to type my left, right content static
        is there a way? */
    }
    #left{
        float:left;
        width: 50px;
    }
    #right{
        float:left;
        width: 50px;
    }
    #bottom{
        /*what do i have to do in here?
        float:*/
    }
```

Comment: Based on your css, you would want `clear:left; width: 100px;`.  Based on your **description**, you would want to change your widths to percentages: `width: 50%`, and then bottom would be `width: 100%', but there's always complicating factors, such as: is there padding? Margin? etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

Set `clear:both` on `#bottom`. Add `width:50%` to both `#left`/`#right`.

Finally, specify the borders on the elements and add `box-sizing` in order to include the borders in the element's width calculations.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/saBE2/)

```
#content {
    border:1px solid black;
}
#content > div {
    height:100px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
#left {
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    border-right:1px solid black;
}
#right {
    float:right;
    width: 50%;
}
#bottom {
    border-top:1px solid black;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want for the bottom div:

```
#bottom{
    clear: both;
    }
```

Comment: This is a very incomplete answer.  How wide should it be?

Comment: The width is inherited from the container. By default, any div will automatically fill 100% of the width of its parent element.

Answer (score 0):

For #bottom, you want `float:left;width:100px;` Just try that, see if it works.

You could also try using positions to do it, if you don't need the size of them to change:which it looks like you don't. For example:

```
#Left {width:50px;height:50px;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;} 
#Right {width:50px;height:50px;position:absolute;left:50px;top:0px;}
#Bottom {width:100px;position:absolute;left:0px;top:50px;}
```

I feel much more confident the second will work.

Comment: I meant to do float:left. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it personally: http://jsfiddle.net/T5fW3/

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="top">
        <div id="left">
            <div class="container"> Left </div>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <div class="container"> Right </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
        Bottom
    </div>
</div>
```

I use a container so that if you want to add styles (border, margins, padding etc) they don't mess up the 50%.  You can now resize content to whatever size and your proportions will still be the same.

```
#content{
    /* the width in here will be changed 
    width: this requirment will be changed
    i dont' want to type my left, right content static
    is there a way? */
}
#left{
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
}
#right{
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
}
#bottom{
    border: 1px solid black;
    clear: both;
}

.container {
    border: 1px solid black;    
}
```

the border in the container class and bottom id is there just for illustration.  If you were to add the border to #left or #right your layout will break.  Notice also, I use 50% instead of 50px.